# How to handle a 204 response in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery

As I have declared success and error ajax options, where the response is 204, the ajax method goes to option success which leads to an error.

As per the documentation we can use, StatusCode or Complete methods but the disadvantage here is have to declare all the status code like 2?? series, 3?? series, 4?? series! As these response are dynamic and I am not sure about the http status code.

So, which is better way to handle http status code in jquery ajax?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface.  The third argument in the done function is a jqXHR object.  This object has a property for the http status code of the result.

> jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}); An alternative
>   construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces
>   the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for
>   implementation details.
>   [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
      beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
          xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"); 
      }
    }).done(function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       console.log(jqXHR.status); //handle your 204 or other status codes here
    });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/fVa7X/

Assuming you want to treat all non 200 status codes as an error you could do something like this:

```
var p = $.ajax({
          url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
          beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
             xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"); 
          }
        });

p.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if(jqXHR.status !== 200) {
     handleError(jqXHR.status);
     return;
  }
  // Normal processing here
});

p.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   handleError(jqXHR.status); 
});
```

Comment: can you explain me the jqXHR.done method with any example? how to handle the status code?

Comment: I provided a fiddle showing how you could test for the status code.  How you handle it depends on the context of the application you are building.

Comment: Does the above done method handles only the deprecated jqXHR.success() method? For error handling do I need to create separate method? Bcoz I tried to play around the jsfiddle by changing the URL and it doesn't handle error code!

Comment: @JohnSmith read the docs I linked =) I don't want to paste the whole section on the jqXHR Object to stack overflow.

Answer (score 12):

The solution above is a nice solution but for someone who already defines "success" and "error" on many components, this involves a lot of changes of code.

After a reading on the documentation, it is rather easy to get status code on success too :

```
jQuery.ajax({
..
'success' : function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status == "204") {

    }
},
error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
        // Manage error 
    },
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ => statusCode

Then to check status code, a **jqXHR.status** will do the trick

Comment: Will success fire if the server responds with an empty body?

Comment: is empty body an error code ? I assume that it is not; therefore; success will be fired

Comment: I tested this the other day, a 204 with an empty body causes the jquery ajax call to blow up and throw error even though the code clearly says it's a successful no content response. Jquery demands every 200 with Json content type to have valid Json in the body even if it's an empty object. It's a little silly if you ask me. They defended it to the grave and insist it's poor server design to not return a body.

Comment: If anyone finds this, put this code in your ajax complete event https://hastebin.com/menobayogu.js