# Console Error - Parsing AJAX JSON Parsing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I've been having an issue with AJAX parsing a JSON Array from a webservice I'm creating. My front end is a simple ajax & jquery combo to display results returned from the webservice I'm creating.

I'm getting an error within Chrome's console stating "cannot read the length property of undefined" despite knowing that there are results from my database query.

After looking for an answer for days I still cannot figure out why I get the console error.

Thank you for any help! :)

```js
function ajaxrequest(e)
{ 
 var r = $('#region').val();
 var t = $('#type').val();
 console.log(r,t);
 $.ajax('https://URL...../.../POI/POI_LOOKUP.php',
 { type: 'GET',
    data: 'type='+t+'&region='+r+'&format=json',
    success: onSuccess }
 );
}

function onSuccess(data,status,xmlHTTP)
{
 var html = "<table><th>name</th><th>type</th><th>country</th><th>region</th>";
 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
 {
 html = html + '<tr><td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[i].type + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[i].country + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[i].region + '</td></tr>';  
 }
 html = html + '</table>';
 $('#results').html(html);
 console.log(data);
 console.log(status);
}
```

Here is my PHP to search and return all results:

```
IF ($type == "any" && !isset($region)) /* Search DB for all types of POI for all regions*/
    {
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest;");
        $statement->execute();
        $row = $statement->fetch();

        if ($row == false)
        {   
            header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
        }
        else
        {
            $allResults = array();
            while($row != false) 
            {
                $allResults[] = $row;
                $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            echo json_encode($allResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(data);` at the start of `onSuccess`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.onSuccess [as success] (POI_HOME.html:35)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:6)
onSuccess @ POI_HOME.html:35
c @ jquery.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4
k @ jquery.min.js:6
r @ jquery.min.js:6

Comment: Basically no data when I know the SQL query is working fine.

Comment: I can see that you haven't decoded the JSON coming back from the web service. Either you need to specify, dataType: "json", in your jQuery Ajax call. Or you need to perform something like var jsonData = JSON.parse(data) in the first line of you onSuccess function.

Comment: Other queries run depending on what the users enters on the front end, but this error will come up if there are no results returned too. So it works to an extent but for the first query (posted) and ones where no results are returned it seems my web service is encoding and empty JSON array?

Comment: I was lead to believe AJAX decodes JSON naively Guillermo, as I said above some quires work fine but others with no results returned will give me the error as it seems a blank json array is being sent back to my front end opposed to just the header.

Comment: When you inspect the response in the network request of your browser tools (usually can press F12 to see them), does it show the expected JSON was returned from the server?

Comment: You could even just put the URL with parameters directly into a browser and see what response you get, and then View Source. You should see the JSON, hopefully.

Comment: it shows a response with nothing (No preview available). If I run another query that works then I can see all of objects in the array. So it seems the webservice is sending me nothing. The query for the first question (posted above will obviously contain all the records in the database though so I don't understand. Perhaps maybe that first IF statement is being ignored?

Comment: If your query doen't has any argument, use `query` instead of `prepare` plus `execute` to remove the overhead created, without parse don't need `prepare`. For ajax, take a look at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365380/returning-variables-from-ajax-php-file/40365561#40365561

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should pass back empty results, if there are no results, and let the Javascript decide what to do (display a nice friendly message to the user). I haven't tested this, it's just for guidance, be warned.

**PHP**

```
if ($type == "any" && !isset($region)) /* Search DB for all types of POI for all regions*/
{
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest;");
        $statement->execute();
        $results = $statement->fetchAll();
        if (count($results)!=0){
            echo json_encode($results);
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
        }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

You may want to handle the 204 response separately: [How to handle a 204 response in jquery ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219595/how-to-handle-a-204-response-in-jquery-ajax). The code below assumes you may receive an empty JSON response.

```
function onSuccess(data,status,xmlHTTP)
{
    if (data.length==0) {
       alert("Friendly user message"); 
       return;
    }
    var html = "<table><th>name</th><th>type</th><th>country</th><th>region</th>";
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
    html = html + '<tr><td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[i].type + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[i].country + '</td>' + '<td>' + data[i].region + '</td></tr>';  
    }
    html = html + '</table>';
    $('#results').html(html);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses guys, it's appreciated. In order to display a message to the user I was going to use the header information Guillermo. As it's a webservice I'm creating clients will use the header info to display their own custom messages. I tried the code you posted with no luck, possibly due the lack of stating the array?

Comment: The idea is to always return valid JSON even if there are no results. fetchAll() should always return an array even if there are no rows: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php. You can check the length first if you wish to send a 204 response. I'll modify my answer. You will of course, have to handle the 204 response in you Ajax call.

Comment: I understand that Guillermo. It seems that checking if the $region variable was not set resulted in no results, I edited it to just check if its blank ( $region =="") and I'm now getting results. I tried your suggestion (PHP) for my web service and all my results were coming back as undefined. I now face the challenge of sending a blank valid JSON response to stop the "Cannot read length" console error I get when no results are returned.

Comment: Thanks you everyone for taking time out to help me! Much appreciated!